# Which prefix to use before family relatives to refer to their past generation?

Tags: word-choice

Which prefix is appropriate to use before family relatives(nieces, nephews and etc) to refer to the generation before them?

For the sake of clarification and better understanding, I'll give a few examples.

Example 1: Grand-niece or Great-niece?

Example 2: Grand-nephew or Great-nephew?

Example 3: Grand-uncle or Great-uncle?

Example 4 : Great-aunt or Grand-aunt?

I'd appreciate anyone who could answer this question, which could the one wandering in many other minds other than mine.

Answer (score 25):

Great going up, grand going down is the general rule. Those of us that read the Paddington Bear stories to our children are well acquainted with Great Aunt Lucy...

[image: Relationship naming explained]

However - I have also seen the term grand-uncle... It sounds wrong to me but there may be regional variations

Comment: Illustrative image, indeed. (+1)

Comment: The post is so nice but I don't know which prefix should I actually put before the names? Like I don't whether I should put great or grand before aunt, uncle, niece, nephew and etc.

Comment: To me, it seems that the rule is "grand, then greats", with the exemption of "Great Aunt or Uncle", which would explain the use of the term "Grand Uncle".

Comment: @GforOevOerD So, if we're just looking over 2 generations each way Grand-Niece -> Niece -> Aunt -> Great-Aunt

Comment: The first sentence of your answer (with the "general rule") is completely contradicted by the image, which is the part that I suspect is receiving the upvotes.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You might be getting confused by  _grand parent_ that looks like _grand_ modifying _parent_.  If you ignore that one case every other one works as described by the general rule.

Comment: @Ukko What about all the other cases with "grand" in the up direction and "great" in the down direction? If you ignore that one case there are still a lot more that contradict the "rule".

Comment: -1, Yeah, that first sentence is completely contradicted by the image. "Great going up, grand going down". For example, we have *grand* parent and great *grand* uncle going up, *great* grand child going down.

Comment: I'm going to edit this for some clarification. When I posted it was a quick answer answer to a simple question - I never anticipated the attention that it would get overnight. It's one of the quirks of the SE community that you can spend hours researching an answer only for it to be ignored and then a 3 minute response like this takes off :) The 'General rule' was only meant to cover the scope of the OPs question. I'll try to make that clearer later today if I get a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Great-niece.
2. Great-nephew.
3. Great-uncle.
4. Great-aunt.

Your sibling's great-grandchildren are your great-great-nieces and great-great-nephews, and your great-grandparents' siblings are your great-great-uncles and great-great-aunts. The element "grand-" is not involved anywhere here.

"Grand-" is used only for direct ancestors and direct descendants. Your parents' parents are your grandparents; their parents are your great-grandparents and so on. Your children's children are your grandchildren; their children are your great-grandchildren and so on. There is only one "grand", and if there are any greats then the greats go before the grand.

Comment: We also have grand niece/nephew and (great) grand uncle/aunt. Those are not direct ancestors or descendants.